# How to catch an ngrx action triggered from effect in UI component?

Tags: angular5, angular6, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am new to the ngrx state management and I'm using **@ngrx/store** and **effect of 6.0.1**, suppose I would like to **save a new member contact** so I have following prepared:

- **member.effect.ts**

  ```
  @Effect()
  memberContactCreate$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(MemberActions.MemberActionTypes.MemberContactCreate),
      switchMap((action: MemberActions.MemberContactCreate) => {
          return this.memberService.createMemberDetail(action.payload);
      }),
      map(
          (response) => {
              console.log('MemberContactCreate$ MemberContactCreate response: ', response);
              if (!response.didError) {
                  return new MemberActions.MemberContactCreateSuccess(response.model as MemberDetailResponse);
              } else {
                  return new MemberActions.MemberContactCreateFailure(response.errorMessage);
              }
          },
      ),
  );
  ```
- **in my member contact component submit I will dispatch the create action**

  `this.store.dispatch(new fromAction.MemberContactCreate(<MemberDetailRequest>this.memberDetailForm.value));`

However, I would like to display a toastr or notification that if my member  successfully created from server, which is defined in my @Effect method, return the new action "**MemberActions.MemberContactCreateSuccess**", **but how could I catch this action in my component as soon as it gets fired?** I tried to do something like below and put it in my ngOnInit and **thought it could be used like a subscription but it's not**, in fact it fires everytime like page load or even I did not dispatch my memberContactCreate action...

```
this.store.select(fromSelector.getMemberCreateSuccess)
      .subscribe((stateSelector) => {
        console.log('getMemberCreateSuccess: ', stateSelector);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.toastr('Hooray',
            'New contact has been created successfully!');
        }, 800);
        this.tableData = stateSelector;
      });
```

So how could my component interact with my triggered ngrx action just like subject/subscription? I've been reading a lot materials online but most of the example stops at "**CreateSuccessful**" action which just pushed an item into stored object list, **there is no continued UI interaction after that...**So how should the component receive or catch the **MemberContactCreateSuccess/Failure** action and let user know your action is success or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't handle the notifications within the component, but I would use @ngrx/effects to show/hide notifications. I briefly touch this in [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#3-showing-notifications).

But if it's really necessary you can listen to your actions in your component just like you do in effects. You'll have to inject `Actions` in your component, use the  `ofType`
operator just like in the effects. The only difference is that you'll have to subscribe on the `actions` observable within the component (in ngrx/effects this is done for you).

Comment: thank you very much and I've read your article which is really helpful! I seemed have a little idea on my side but wasn't quite sure. For example, in your tutorial, effect CustomerActionTypes.Get you're returning a new action "GetCustomersSuccess" at the end, 1) should I perform the show modal/toastr inside the same effect? Maybe at the end in a new map or switchMap operation? 2) If so, should my effect become dispatch true or false? 3) Or maybe I should create a new effect on GetCustomersSuccess action and handle modal/toastr inside?

Comment: I am also very curious about your second suggestion which "listen to actions in component", do you have any sample code or tutorial on that? I would like to know where should I put my listener like in ngOnInit or somewhere else? Do I need to use ngOnDestroy to unsubscribe just like using subscription and subject?

Comment: I don't have any example code, but you can listen on these changes in `ngOnInit` and you should indeed unsubscribe. 
it could something as `this.actions.pipe(ofType('FOO'), takeUntill(this.destroyed)).subscribe(() => this.showToastr);`. Let me know if you need some more details.